# What's a good estimate of $\sum\limits_{k \mid n} {n \choose k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients

*Question*: What's a good estimate of $\sum\limits_{k \mid n} {n \choose k}$?

We have found an OEIS page for that: https://oeis.org/A056045
$1, 3, 4, 11, 6, 42, 8, 107, 94, 308, 12, 1718, 14, 3538, 3474, 14827, 18, 68172, 20, 205316, 117632, 705686, 24, 3587174, 53156, 10400952, 4689778, 41321522, 30, 185903342, 32, 611635179, 193542210, 2333606816, 7049188, 10422970784, 38, \dots$

*Remark*: This sum appears naturally for getting an easy estimate of the cardinal of the subgroup lattice $\mathcal{L}(G)$ of a group $G$ of order $n$. For this post, we are interested in the sum above, not $|\mathcal{L}(G)|$.

Comment: This will depend  a lot on the arithmetic structure of $n$.

Comment: That depends on the behaviour of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ over the unit circle, that may be quite erratic. The problem to estimate the coefficients of a cyclotomic polynomial through Ramanujan sums and other techniques is well-known (see Erdos), but I would not expect any global estimate other than extremely weak ones.

Comment: Obviously it is bounded above by $2^n$. Yet then  $\binom{n}{n/2}$ alone is around $2^n/\sqrt{n}$ or something like that. So it can't be much better for even $n$.

Comment: @quid: that's a pretty good point.

Comment: I suppose if one wants something better one could improve the upper bound by taking into account that there cannot be any contriution for n/3 < k < n/2. The sum for $k \le n/3$ already should not be that large in a relative sense for large $n$.

Comment: Since $\binom nk$ is an increasing function of $k$ for $0\le k\le \frac n2$, it's obvious that the largest term in the sum will be $\binom n{n/m}$ where $m$ is the smallest divisor of $n$ greater than $1$. And the binomial coefficients have such a range of sizes that the whole sum can probably be shown to be at most $2\binom nm$. (For example, think how much smaller $\binom n{n/(m+1)}$ is than $\binom n{n/m}$.)

Comment: @GregMartin That sounds reasonable, although I would have specified the key term differently (for the same result) - it uses the largest factor $m$ less than $n$. The multiplier to get from $n\choose m $ to the total drops away quickly; for $36$ the multiplier would be just under $1.15$, for $60$ it is under $1.04$. (For $45$ it is much lower, under $1.003$)

Comment: Fair enough. Although computationally, it's easier to look for the smallest divisor of $n$ than the largest divisor; and it allows one to separate integers into families where the behavior of the sum will be similar.